# Javascript assigning data from one to antoher object adds duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I tried to find a solution to my problem, but was unable to find a matching topic unfortunately. I am new to Javascript so I guess it's my understanding what's the problem. Anyhow I don't get it after trying for days. So hep is appreciated a lot - thanks.

Problem:
I try to map some data from a JSON object fetched from an API (Source) and map it to a different data structure (Result). Somehow my assignment is generating duplicates even if I think I explicitly assign to exactly on position in the data object.

Sorry Code example is a bit longer, but for sure the probelm is in the very end of the example. In debugger I can see that in each iteration of the loop all values get assigned to all result series.data alwas - but do not understand why.

My Code is:

```
function Sample(){

    // Source data from the API simplified
    var SourceData = {
        "hits": 4,
        "job": [
            {
                "status": "FINISHED",
                "type": "IMPORT",
            },
            {
                "status": "FAILED",
                "type": "EXPORT",
            },
            {
                "status": "RUNNING",
                "type": "TRANSCODE",
            },
            {
                "status": "FINISHED",
                "type": "TRANSCODE",
            }
        ]
    };

    // Helper variable
    var status = [];


    //Initialize Result data object
    var ResultData = {
    labels: [],
    series: []
    };

    // Used to to extend the Result Data Object later
    var placeholderSeries = {name:'', data: []}

    // Get job types and Status from SourceData and write as labels and series.name to result object without duplicates 
    for (var i=0; i < SourceData.job.length; i++){

        var typeExists = ResultData.labels.indexOf(SourceData.job[i].type);
        var statusExists = status.indexOf(SourceData.job[i].status);

        if (typeExists == -1){
        ResultData.labels.push(SourceData.job[i].type);
        ResultData.labels.sort();
        }

        if (statusExists == -1){

        // Fill array with Status values without duplicates
        status.push(SourceData.job[i].status);
        // Fill result data with empty sub structure
        ResultData.series.push(placeholderSeries);
        }
    }

  // Write a series name for each job status corresponding with the status values of the source
 for(var i=0; i < ResultData.series.length; i++)
  {
      // THIS LINE DOESN'T WORK AS I WOULD EXPECT
      ResultData.series[i].name = status[i]; 
   }
   console.log(JSON.stringify(ResultData,null,4));
}
```

The Outcome I get is:

```
{
    "labels": [
        "EXPORT",
        "IMPORT",
        "TRANSCODE"
    ],
    "series": [
        {
            "name": "RUNNING",
            "data": []
        },
        {
            "name": "RUNNING",
            "data": []
        },
        {
            "name": "RUNNING",
            "data": []
        }
    ]
}
```

The Outcome expected is:

```
{
    "labels": [
        "EXPORT",
        "IMPORT",
        "TRANSCODE"
    ],
    "series": [
        {
            "name": "FINISH",
            "data": []
        },
        {
            "name": "FAILED",
            "data": []
        },
        {
            "name": "RUNNING",
            "data": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hi, Zatze welcome to Stackoverflow. After looking at your code it seems the `placeholderSeries` is being added three times to the `series` array. The array holds 3 references to the same object, and since it's the same object when the property is updated it looks like it's triplicated.

Comment: Thanks for the help, understood the problem now and could fix it!

Answer (score 1):

```js
function Sample() {
        // Source data from the API simplified
        var SourceData = {
            hits: 4,
            job: [
                {
                    status: "FINISHED",
                    type: "IMPORT"
                },
                {
                    status: "FAILED",
                    type: "EXPORT"
                },
                {
                    status: "RUNNING",
                    type: "TRANSCODE"
                },
                {
                    status: "FINISHED",
                    type: "TRANSCODE"
                }
            ]
        };

        // Helper variable
        var status = [];

        //Initialize Result data object
        var ResultData = {
            labels: [],
            series: []
        };


        // Get job types and Status from SourceData and write as labels and series.name to result object without duplicates
        for (var i = 0; i < SourceData.job.length; i++) {
            var typeExists = ResultData.labels.indexOf(SourceData.job[i].type);
            var statusExists = status.indexOf(SourceData.job[i].status);
            
            if (typeExists == -1) {
                ResultData.labels.push(SourceData.job[i].type);
                ResultData.labels.sort();
            }

            if (statusExists == -1) {
                // Fill array with Status values without duplicates
                status.push(SourceData.job[i].status);
                // Fill result data with empty sub structure
                var placeholderSeries = { name: "", data: [] };
                ResultData.series.push(placeholderSeries);
            }
        }

        // Write a series name for each job status corresponding with the status values of the source
        for (var i = 0; i < ResultData.series.length; i++) {
            // THIS LINE DOESN'T WORK AS I WOULD EXPECT
            ResultData.series[i].name = status[i];
        }
        console.log(JSON.stringify(ResultData, null, 4));
    }
    Sample();
```

Basically you used the reference type wrong.
You've added the same placeholderSeries to the array multiple times, but you've added the same object.

When you are working with reference type you are not storing the value in that variable, you are storing an reference to it, you can point multiple variables to the same value.

If you have for example:

```
var x = {"name": "John"};
var y = x;
y.name = "John2";
```

both x and y will be modified because they point to the same object.

As a fix for your problem you should move the placeholderSeries declaration inside the loop. In this way for each loop a new object will be created.

Comment: Thanks for the help, understood the problem now and could fix it! The suggestion was exactly what I did and what clariefied my wrong way of thinking.

Comment: I am glad that I helped you!

Answer (score 1):

With newer versions of JavaScript [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) can be used like this:

```js
// Source data from the API simplified
const sourceData = {
    "hits": 4,
    "job": [
        {
            "status": "FINISHED",
            "type": "IMPORT"
        },
        {
            "status": "FAILED",
            "type": "EXPORT"
        },
        {
            "status": "RUNNING",
            "type": "TRANSCODE"
        },
        {
            "status": "FINISHED",
            "type": "TRANSCODE"
        }
    ]
};

const labels = [...new Set(sourceData.job.map(it => it.type))];
const uniqueStatuses = [...new Set(sourceData.job.map(it => it.status))];

const resultData = {
    labels,
    series: uniqueStatuses.map(it =>({"name": it, data: []}))
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(resultData, null, 4));
```

Answer (score 0):

- `statusExists` always `= -1`
- you always `.push(placeholderSeries);`
- `placeholderSeries` every time it is **the same object** (`var placeholderSeries = { name: '', data: [] }`)

In the last iteration loop:

```
  // status:  [ 'FINISHED', 'FAILED', 'RUNNING' ]
  for (var i = 0; i < ResultData.series.length; i++) {
    // THIS LINE DOESN'T WORK AS I WOULD EXPECT
    ResultData.series[i].name = status[i];
  }
```

we set the value of a **single object** to `'RUNNING'`

Comment: Thanks for the help, understood the problem now and could fix it!